# Login validation not working on my account page(wordpress)

Tags: wordpress, validation, authentication

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uk1eQ.jpg)

login validation error coming on main page, but error on wrong id password not coming on my account login page theme is Moleez wordpress and link is https://thepremiumleathers.com/my-account/ help.

Comment: It is assumed you have custom code? If so, please provide code in your question and base your question on said code. Alternatively, if it is not custom code you will need to contact 'Moleez'.

Comment: No custom coded the login modal in the main page coming but in my account page error on wrong id/password not comes.

Comment: My apologies, I dont understand your comment - whether or not you have custom code. Without code to work on in your question, a solution cannot be attempted. "My Account" is usually Woocommerce?

Comment: Thanks but i resolved it..

Comment: I didn't use custom code because there is no need it by default woocommerce feature. I resolved it by using another plugin no need to custom code now.